# Syntax for `apply` pandas function in ruby

Tags: python, pandas, ruby, dataframe, pycall

I need to convert a python script into ruby. I use for that the gems [Pandas](https://github.com/mrkn/pandas.rb) and [Numpy](https://github.com/mrkn/numpy.rb) which make the work quite simple.

For example I have these kind of lines:

```py
# python
# DF is a dataframe from Pandas

DF['VAL'].ewm(span = vDAY).mean()
DF['VOLAT'].rolling(vDAY).std()
```

so no question asked, I convert like this:

```rb
# ruby
df['VAL'].ewm(span: vDAY).mean
df['VOLAT'].rolling(vDAY).std
```

easy.

---

But I have a function `apply` from Pandas which takes a function as first argument and I really don't know how to convert it in ruby.
It's something like that :

```py
# python
import numpy as np

DF['VAL'].rolling(vDAY).apply(lambda x: np.polyfit(range(len(x)), x, 1)[0])
# output=> NaN or Float
```

I tried to decomposed the lambda like this:

```rb
# ruby
polyfit = ->(x) { t = Numpy.polyfit((0...x.size).to_a, x, 1); t[0] }

puts polyfit.call(<insert Array argument>) 
#=> I have a satisfying output for my lambda

# but...
df['VAL'].rolling(vDAY).apply(&polyfit)
# output=> `apply': <class 'TypeError'>: must be real number, not NoneType (PyCall::PyError)

# or
df['VAL'].rolling(vDAY).apply{ |x| polyfit.call(x) }
# output=> `apply': <class 'TypeError'>: apply() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func' (PyCall::PyError)

# or
df['VAL'].rolling(vDAY).apply(polyfit)
#output=> `apply': <class 'TypeError'>: must be real number, not NoneType (PyCall::PyError)

# or
df['VAL'].rolling(vDAY).apply(:polyfit)
# output=> `apply': <class 'TypeError'>: 'str' object is not callable (PyCall::PyError)
```

It's obviously not working. The problem is this "x" argument in the python inline syntax that I really don't know how to get it "the ruby way"

If someone can "translate" this `apply` function from python syntax to ruby, it would be really nice :)

I just want to point out that I'm a ruby/rails developer and I don't know python professionally speaking.

---

UPDATE:

Ok, it's a complete misunderstanding of python code for my part: `apply` needs a function argument as a callable object. So in ruby it's not a lambda but a Proc I need.

So the solution for those who encounter the same problem:

```rb
# ruby
polyfit = Proc.new { t = Numpy.polyfit((0...x.size).to_a, x, 1); t[0] }
df['VAL'].rolling(vDAY).apply(polyfit)
```

Comment: It is weird that a Python error is bubbling up on the Ruby side. Are you sure `t[0]` is not `nil` for some reason?

Answer (score -1):

> If someone can "translate" this `apply` function from python syntax to ruby, it would be really nice

The equivalent Ruby syntax is:

```ruby
DF['VAL'].rolling(vDAY).apply(-> x { np.polyfit(range(len(x)), x, 1)[0] })
```

Comment: I'm in a ruby file, I can't use python methods like `len()`, it's undefined.